# IconComponent: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired ( material ui ) error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've tried to migrate material ui from `v3` to `v4` , but have got this issue

[image]

[image]

I thought that this issue related to prop `IconComponent` for `Select` component , but after adding it to each `@material-ui/core/Select` component in my project it didn't help .

Also I've found this changes in material ui github repository https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/17390/files maybe it will help

Also you can find below all my dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "0.0.2",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.4.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "3.0.1",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "3.2.6",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.4.3",
    "axios": "0.19.0",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "connected-react-router": "6.4.0",
    "date-fns": "2.0.0-alpha.27",
    "enzyme": "3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.14.0",
    "history": "4.6.3",
    "humps": "2.0.0",
    "jss": "^10.0.0",
    "jss-camel-case": "6.1.0",
    "jss-default-unit": "8.0.2",
    "jss-expand": "5.3.0",
    "jss-extend": "6.2.0",
    "jss-global": "3.0.0",
    "jss-nested": "6.0.1",
    "jss-props-sort": "6.0.0",
    "jss-vendor-prefixer": "8.0.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.14",
    "moment": "2.23.0",
    "normalizr": "3.3.0",
    "prop-types": "15.6.2",
    "qs": "6.5.2",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-dropzone": "10.1.4",
    "react-hot-loader": "4.8.8",
    "react-image": "2.1.1",
    "react-intl": "2.7.2",
    "react-intl-po": "2.2.2",
    "react-intl-redux": "2.0.2",
    "react-motion": "0.5.2",
    "react-pose": "4.0.8",
    "react-redux": "7.0.3",
    "react-router": "4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "react-spinners": "0.4.7",
    "react-universal-component": "4.0.0",
    "recompose": "0.30.0",
    "redux": "4.0.1",
    "redux-axios-middleware": "4.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.8",
    "redux-form": "8.2.2",
    "redux-form-validators": "^3.2.2",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "2.1.0",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
    "store2": "2.7.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "2.0.1"
  },
```

Comment: Can you post your JSX?

Answer (score 5):

*[elementType](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)* was added in prop-types 15.7.0, and you are using 15.6.2 
Upgrade your prop-types to version 15.7.0 or higher and the error should disappear.